# Why didn't the Vashta Nerada eat the statues?

Tags: doctor-who

In 'Silence of the Library' and 'Forest of the Dead', the Doctor and Donna are stuck in a library and have to battle micro-organisms that eat flesh.

In the library there are statues with real human faces, implying real flesh.

My question is, if the Vashta Nerada eat flesh, any flesh, why didn't they eat the faces on the statues?

[image]

Comment: Weren't they just synthetic copies of the faces? That is, not actual flesh...

Comment: No they said donated from flesh archives

Answer (score 7):

The most relevant quote is from [Silence in the Library](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/30-8.htm) :

> **MARK NODE:** This flesh aspect was donated by Mark Chambers on the
>   occasion of his death.
>
> **DONNA:** It's a real face?.
>
> **MARK NODE:** It has been actualised individually for you from the many
>   facial aspects **saved to our extensive flesh banks**. Please enjoy.
>
> **DONNA:** It chose me a dead face it thought I'd like? That statue's got
>   a real dead person's face on it.

The implication being that it's not a real living face, but simply a representation (an *aspect*) of a face, made out of synthetic flesh.

The Vasta Nerada are described as eating "meat" (including "roadkill") so the only reasonable possibility for why they haven't eaten it, is that [node](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Node) isn't wearing a meat face.

Comment: Donna has some of the best quotes out of the whole series.

Comment: @Omegacron - Urgh. Worst Doctor Who character ever. I'd rather have had K9 back again.

Comment: No argument there, but she still got some of the best lines. She definitely ain't no Rose, Martha, Amy, or Clara. They probably gave her comedy lines to take advantage of her existing comedy skit reputation in the UK.

Comment: @Omegacron - I couldn't believe it when they made her a main character. I actually thought it was a spoof right up to the day that they broadcast the show.

Comment: I'm sure a lot of people did - she was only known for her parodies & skits, with ZERO real acting credits to her name (AFAIK). I was familiar with the name from her skits, but didn't really put 2 + 2 together until I saw her face on the show. I also noticed that her original character was almost a parody of other companions - she was rude, snarky, and wanted nothing to do with The Doctor.